# picking two elements from JSON array and adding to a new json array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-maps

I have a JSON Array which looks like this on Stringify:

```
 [{"lat":40,"lng":90},{"lat":41,"lng":91},{"lat":42,"lng":92},{"lat":43,"lng":94}]
```

and so on ( Actual  array will have more entries).
I want to pick two elements at a time, create a JSON array (exact same format as above) and plot each as a line on google Maps.

Code I wrote goes like this. `json` is what I get on using `JSON.parse` whose stringify version is mentioned above.

```
var x=[];
for(var i=0;i<json.length/2;i+=2)
{
x=json[i];
x+=json[i+1];
//var y=JSON.parse(x);
console.log(x);
}
```

As expected I get a `[object Object][object Object]` output. Can I directly use this to plot? I don't think so because I get this if I stringify x

```
 "[object Object][object Object]"
```

I think I'm doing this wrong or missing out on some basic thing. Not that well-versed in Javascript. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use push method to add values in array.

```
var x=[];
for(var i=0;i<json.length/2;i+=2)
{
x.push(json[i]);
x.push(json[i+1]);
console.log(x);
}
```

And you can use the resultant `array` like this

```
var lat = x[0].lat;
var lng = x[0].lng;
```

Or you can `loop` over array as needed.

Comment: Perfect! A very basic thing I was overlooking. Thanks!!